# Como publicar no JitPack artefatos Maven com "flavour" definidas por perfil Maven?

Tags: maven, integração-contínua

Eu tenho uma série de dependências que ora preciso do seu "sabor" normal, hora preciso de seu "sabor" sem lambdas.

Eu resolvo isso tendo o perfil `retrolambda` habilitado ou não. Um dos meus projetos que preciso disso é [`totalcross-functional-toolbox`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox). Atualmente, o que eu tenho é um build no gitlab-CI para publicar num repositório de artefatos privado, porém estou pensando em mudar para o JitPack. O que faço atualmente está no [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/-/blob/83af3f4cb23cd03385dad2fdf0258deae48c6c4d/.gitlab-ci.yml#L27-30) do projeto:

```
archive-functional-toolbox:
  script:
    - ./mvnw $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -pl :totalcross-functional-toolbox,:totalcross-functional-toolbox-bom,:gwt-functional-toolbox-is-serializable -am
    - ./mvnw $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -pl :totalcross-functional-toolbox,:totalcross-functional-toolbox-bom -P retrolambda
```

Note como, para publicar os dois sabores, eu mando executar `clean deploy` habilitando ou não o perfil `retrolambda`. Essa diferença de sabores eu coloca na versão. A priori, a versão é `2.0.1${revision}`, se eu não colocar o perfil `retrolambda` acontece que `${revision}` expande para string vazia, já com o perfil expande para `+retrolambda`.

No caso, como o JitPack controla o ciclo de vida, tem como eu detectar qual o "flavor" que está sendo requisitado para fazer o build adequado? Eu vou requerer ora o artefato `com.gilab.geosales-open-source:totalcross-functional-toolbox:2.0.1`, ora o artefato `com.gilab.geosales-open-source:totalcross-functional-toolbox:2.0.1+retrolambda`, como saber qual artefato estou requerendo para gerar corretamente a versão desejada?

> Por hora, ignorar o fato de que o projeto de exemplo é um projeto Maven multi-módulo, a resposta pode considerar apenas como se fosse um projeto Maven simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JitPack permite que você coloque um script de build personalizado. Nesse script, ele [garante algumas variáveis](https://jitpack.io/docs/BUILDING/#build-environment). No caso, a variável garantida `VERSION` traz a versão desejada a ser gerada. Por exemplo, se em algum lugar tiver a dependência `com.gitlab.geosales-open-source:totalcross-resultset-extractor:1.0.1-retrolambda`, JitPack irá passar a variável `VERSION=1.0.1-retrolambda` para o script.

Então, para o caso de a versão passar algum esquema de "sabor" para o artefato gerado, é preciso fazer algum processamento na variável `VERSION` passada. [Por exemplo](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-resultset-extractor/-/blob/9170f8f8197073cb87776ab404ba6b5fed7baec4/jitpack.yml):

```bsh
./mvnw `[[ "$VERSION" == *-retrolambda ]] && echo "-P retrolambda"` clean install
```

Aqui se verifica se a versão satisfaz o *glob* `*-retrolambda`; se satisfizer, irá realizar a substituição textual para `-P retrolambda`, caso contrário será substituído pela string vazia. Desse modo, é possível fazer a detecção de "sabor" desejado para o build e usar um perfil Maven associado a ele.

Vale ressaltar que, nos testes, usar `+` como parte da string de versão [não deu muito certo](https://jitpack.io/com/gitlab/geosales-open-source/totalcross-resultset-extractor/-1.0.0+retrolambda-ge57c03c-1/build.log), tanto não reconhecendo corretamente a string de versão como também dizendo que é "versão inválida".

O arquivo de build do JitPack é identificado por `jitpack.yml` na raiz do diretório. Mais informações na [documentação oficial](https://jitpack.io/docs/BUILDING/#custom-commands).